# onMouseDown event in react does not trigger state changes but onClick does

Tags: reactjs

JSX part looks like this:

```
<span className="header_srh_i_c" onMouseDown={this.toggleSearchbar}>
    <i className="fa fa-search"
        id="searchButton"
        name="searchButton"
     />
 </span>
```

function in the same component looks like this:

```
toggleSearchbar(event){
    const eventType = event.type;
    if(this.state.showSearch && this.props.q && length(this.props.q) > 0){
      this.toggleSearching();
    }else{
      console.log("state after", this.state.showSearch)  //false

      this.setState({showSearch:!this.state.showSearch},function (event) {
      console.log("state after", this.state.showSearch) //false
      })
    }
  }
```

state remains `false` event after execution of

```
this.setState({showSearch:!this.state.showSearch},function (event) {
          console.log("state after", this.state.showSearch) //false
          })
```

However, it works just fine if I use `onClick` instead of `onMouseDown`

Comment: I made a simple demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/p71117md/) and it seems to work fine with both `onClick` and `onMouseOver`. Click the text and check output in console.

Comment: On my system, I have tried with console statements as in the piece of code above. Surprisingly, this.state.showSearch is false both before and after state change

Comment: I have a feeling the problem is you need to bind `toggleSearchBar`, e.g.  `onMouseDown={this.toggleSearchBar.bind(this)}`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
this.setState(prev => ({showSearch: !prev.showSearch}), function(){.....})
```

instead of

```
this.setState({showSearch:!this.state.showSearch},function (event) {
      console.log("state after", this.state.showSearch) //false
      })
```