# How to listen for mousdown event in javascript - react-materialize?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mousedown

This is the following code return in react

```
import {
      Input
    } from "react-materialize";

    <Input
        id="fromDate"
        name="from"
        type="date"
        onChange={this.handleChangeFromDate}
     />
```

How to use mousedown event in the following handler

```
handleChangeFromDate(event, value) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let startDate = new Date(value).getTime(value);
}
```

I want to use `event.preventDefault` in `mousedown` event. I have jquery code for this, but not sure how to transform it into js code?

```
$('.datepicker').on('mousedown',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: Which Component you want to add on `MouseDown Event`?

Comment: @zynkn I have modified the question.I want to use it in `handleChangeFromDate` event.

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41699050/onmousedown-event-in-react-does-not-trigger-state-changes-but-onclick-does

Comment: Also check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50175081/how-to-toggle-class-on-mousedown-mouseup-in-react-component/50176340

Answer (score 0):

You can call the same method for mouse down event by calling `onMouseDown` event

```
    onMouseDown={this.handleChangeFromDate}
```

But I am not sure about your '.datepicker' component.  If it is a separate component, you should add `onMouseDown` to that component's props